# How to find a separating hyperplane?

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization, convex-geometry

Let $C$ be the convex subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ defined by:
\begin{align}
C = \{(x,y):~~ \log(x) + \log(y) \geq 1;~~ x\geq 0;~~ y\geq 0\}
\end{align}

According to the [hyperplane separation theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperplane_separation_theorem), if a point $(x_0,y_0)$ is not in $C$, then there is a hyperplane separating $(x_0,y_0)$ from $C$.

MY QUESTION: Given a point $(x_0,y_0)$ with $\log(x_0) + \log(y_0) < 1$, how can I find a hyperplane separating $(x_0,y_0)$ from $C$?

Comment: Take the tangent to the curve $\log(x) + \log(y) = \log(x_0) + \log(y_0)$.

Comment: @daw can you explain in more detail? Is this a general method for finding a separating hyperplane?

Comment: the tangent is below the line $log(x)+log(y)=log(x0)+log(y0)$, which is below $C$.